# Is it possible to reinstall software-manager after uninstalling on ubuntu 18.04? No network connectivity

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, internet, source-packages

So I was having wifi problems and decided to fix it and made the blunderous mistake of executing the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install wicd
sudo apt-get purge network-manager
```

and in doing so I appear to have lost all network access from the network-manager, but haven't gained any network access from wicd.

I realise this was a foolish mistake, and that [help.ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD) says

> For versions of Ubuntu 18.04.1 and later, it's not possible to uninstall network-manager without uninstalling ubuntu-desktop.

So I'm guessing that this is why I can't use wicd for my network connections.
I've also lost access to the settings menu and other fundamental functionalities.

I'm still able to use a usb, so intuitively I think that I should be able to download an appropriate version of the network manager on another computer and transfer them across and run it, but have no idea how to download correctly from windows.

I don't have an older kernel to go back to.

Here are some important command outputs:

```
sudo iwconfig 
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
```

-

```
sudo apt-get install wicd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
wicd is already the newest version (1.7.4+tb2-5).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcolord-gtk1 libnss-myhostname libteamdctl0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 5 not to upgrade.
```

-

```
wicd-cli --wireless -S
Command 'wicd-cli' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install wicd-cli
```

Is it practical to install the network manager in this situation without reinstalling the whole OS?

Comment: There should be a CLI for wicd: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wicd#Connecting_with_wicd-cli

Comment: @muru, Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly I don't have wicd-cli (I've appended the output of a wicd-cli command to the question description).

Comment: If you don't have `wicd-cli`, at least one of `wicd-gtk` or `wicd-ncurses` should be present, because [the `wicd` package requires at least one of them](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/wicd)

Comment: @muru, thank you!!! I used wicd-gtk to reinstall network-manager. Thank you! If you write that as an answer then I'll accept it (sadly I can't up vote your comments or even your answer).

Comment: It might be best if you post an answer showing how you used `wicd-gtk` (I haven't used it in ages myself)

Comment: I literally just entered the command `wicd-gtk` which opened the application, it automatically searched for the wifi connections, I chose the wifi network to connect to and connected. Very simple in the end. Thanks again. I assume that you'd refer to get another answer accepted, otherwise I'll answer it if I don't hear anything from your for a while. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to muru for describing to me in the comments how to solve this problem. I'm writing it as an answer so that others will easily see that this question has been answered.

As wicd had been installed, I just needed to access it.
Suggested command line prompts for this:

`wicd-cli`, `wicd-gtk` or `wicd-ncurses`.

`wicd-gtk` worked for me.

This prompt opened up the GUI for the application, and it automatically searched for nearby wifi networks. I connected to a network, then ran the command:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

This meant that I could access the network as normal. Later I realised that sometimes the wifi would cut suddenly and be completely unable to find any nearby wifi networks. Restarting the computer appeared to fix this only temporarily. To fix it permanently, I removed wicd:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove wicd wicd-gtk
sudo dpkg --purge wicd wicd-gtk
```